# Cannot create Rails project, but sqlite is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to get into Ruby on Rails. I have followed this: http://installrails.com/steps/create_your_first_app

But when I type `rails new sample_app` I get this error:

```
current directory:
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/ext/sqlite3
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190630-14364-17waap6.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.4.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3
```

But if I then runs the `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.1'` line, I get this message, which looks like a success.

```
gem install sqlite3
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
advarsel: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3-3.27.2-2 er opdateret - springer over
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.4.1
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.4.1
Done installing documentation for sqlite3 after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But I still can't create a new project.

Any Ideas?

Comment: open the terminal and run this command `sqlite3 --version` to ensure that your system currently has sqlite installed

Comment: 3.8.7.2 2014-11-18 20:57:56

Answer (score 0):

## Execute below commands it may help to you

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
gem install sqlite3
bundle install
```

Comment: okk there need to install ridk :: Follow this for windows```                                   
# Go to this path and type rdk install
C:\Ruby24-x64\bin>ridk install

# it will give you 3 options to be instal  you can add all there like [1,2,3]